# Ruby grep and append

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, and I am trying to grep at beginning of a file.  If matched then append

> "abc..."

For example: file1.txt

> "First line...
>   Second line....
>   So on so forth..."

I have tried these and thought they would work but I was wrong:

```
File.readlines('file1.txt').grep(/^First/).pop('abc')  
File.readlines('file1.txt').grep(/^First/)<<"abc"
```

This give

> ["First line\n", "abc.."] but I was aiming for ["First line abc..\n"]

```
File.write('file1.txt', 'a').grep(/^First/)<<'abc..'
```

Error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `grep' for 1:Fixnum
>         from (irb):4
>        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in`'

Ultimately, I was hoping to achieve this

> First line abc..

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Please always include the original error message and/or stacktrace.

Comment: `file1` defines a string, not a file. Or, is that embedded into a file? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you did is to assign the contents to a variable called `file1`, but that will not yet store the contents in a file. To write a file in Ruby you can do this:

```
data="First line...
Second line....
So on so forth..."

File.open('file1', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(data)
end
```

Now you have a file called `file1` in your file system. Your original commands however still contain errors, because the `grep` method does not exist. If you want to append to an arbitrary line in a file in Ruby, you need to duplicate the contents and write the file from scratch. Here's one possible solution:

```
# read lines
lines = File.readlines('file1')

# append abc to first line if it starts with "First"
#
# =~ performs a regex match against the string.
#
# chomp! is there because we want to append "abc"
# before the newline character, not after it.
if lines.first =~ /^First/
  lines.first.chomp! << "abc"
end

# write lines back to original file
File.open('file1', 'w') do |f|
  lines.each do |line|
    f.puts line
  end
end
```

I would actually suggest something different for the middle part, a Regex match might just be overkill for comparing the beginning of a string. In Ruby, we have the `start_with?` and `end_with?` methods for strings:

```
if lines.first.start_with? 'First'
  lines.first.chomp! << "abc"
end
```

From your question I understand that you want to prevent double appends in case `"abc"` was already appended in a previous run. That's where `end_with?` comes in handy.

```
string_to_append = "abc"
if lines.first.start_with? 'First'
  lines.first.chomp!
  lines.first << string_to_append unless lines.first.end_with?(string_to_append)
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I followed your steps and it worked.
For learning purpose, I tested File.write('file1', 'w') do |f| ... it erased file1.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @snowghost `File.write` will write directly to the file specified in the first parameter its second argument, the string `'w'` in your case. You end up with the file containing only the character `w`. The `do ... end` block you passed will just be ignored because `File.write` simply doesn't use it. Since there is no `File#write` implementation, you have to look up the docs in `IO#write`, the superclass of `File`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-write

Comment: Side note: Again, please be more precise with your error descriptions. The correct description here would have been that you ended up with a file that contains the character `w`, it is not _erased_ in the narrower sense! These details matter, and they often lead to the correct answer. Remote debugging is hard enough already without seeing the entire code.

Comment: Corrected, the file contained the character w.  Thanks again for all the helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since readlines returns an array you can do the following:

Let's say you have

```
# file.txt
First line
Second line

# ruby.rb
file = File.open('path/to/file')
index = File.readlines(file)[0] =~ /^First/ # index = 0 if matches or nil if does not
```

You can read the [docs for String#match (or String#=~)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-3D-7E)